# Inverse of diagonally dominant matrix with equal off-diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetry

Is there an explicit expression for the inverse of strictly diagonally dominant matrix with identical off-diagonal elements?

For example:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & -b & -b \\
                  -b &  c & -b \\
                  -b & -b &  d \end{pmatrix} $$

where $|a|\gt 2|b|$, $|c|\gt 2|b|$, and $|d|\gt 2|b|$. I'm looking for an inverse for an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix with the above property.

Comment: This can be expressed as the inverse of a rank one update of a diagonal matrix, a topic that has been addressed in previous questions.

Comment: Any recommended references that can help?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766089/inverse-of-a-matrix-with-uniform-off-diagonals

Answer (score 10):

The [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) gives the inverse of any rank one update of a matrix for which the inverse is known.

Here we can write your matrix as follows:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & -b & -b \\ -b & c & -b \\ -b & -b & d \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix} a+b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c+b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & d+b \end{pmatrix}
  - b \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Since the first summand is an invertible diagonal matrix (regardless of the actual sign of $b$), we have that the Sherman-Morrison formula can be applied.

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a+b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c+b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & d+b \end{pmatrix}$ and let $u = \begin{pmatrix} -b \\ -b \\ -b \end{pmatrix}$, $v^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.  What you ask for is:

$$ (A + uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \left( \frac{1}{1+ v^T A^{-1} u} \right)
\left( A^{-1} uv^T A^{-1} \right) $$

Note that the first factor in the second term of the right hand side is just a scalar, obtained by taking the reciprocal of the scalar $1+ v^T A^{-1} u$. It multiplies the rank one matrix $A^{-1} uv^T A^{-1}$, showing that the inverse of the rank one update of $A$ is itself a rank one update of $A^{-1}$.